# using x number of a list

Tags: java, list

I want to create objects, add them to a list and then do something with the x-th number of that list. How can I do this?

What I would do with arrays [] :

```
Room [] roomList = new Room [number];

for (int i=0; i < asManyAsIWant; i++){
    Room room = new Room();
    roomList[i] = room;
}

roomList[x].doSomething();
```

What I want to do with List:

```
List<Room> roomList = new  ArrayList<Room> ();

for (int i=0; i < asManyAsIWant; i++){
    Room room = new Room();
    roomList.add(room);
}

roomList[x].doSomething();
```

This last line is the problem, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists provide a [`get(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method, where `i` is the index you want to access.

> E get(int index)
>
> **Returns** the element at the specified position in this
>   list.
>
> **Parameters:** index - index of the element to return Returns: the
>   element at the specified position in this list

Thus your code would look like so:

```
int x = ...;
List<Rom> roomList = new  ArrayList<Rom> ();

for (int i=0; i<asManyAsIWant;i++){
    Room room = new Room();
    roomList.add(room);
}

if((x >= 0) && (x < roomList.size())    //Extra check to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    roomList.get(x).doSomthing();
else
    //Do something when x is larger or smaller than it should be.
```

Comment: @npinti Why `(x > 0)` instead of `(x >= 0)`?

Comment: @Manu: My mistake sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You access the x-th element of a list using the get method.

```
roomList.get(x).doSomthing();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `roomList[x].doSomthing();`

with

```
roomList.get(x).doSomthing();
```

where `x is the current index`

```
   `roomList.get(x)` return actual `Room object` on which you can invoke `doSomthing()` method
```